# Azure Cloud Service redirects to https protocol

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

My Azure Cloud Service production is set to https protocol, but Staging is defined as http.

In the Site URL I do see http: http://14b49449470943dba58da05d131243da.cloudapp.net/ but when I go to the site I is redirected to https protocol.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Are you using cloud services (classic).. just confiming? Have you checked your web.config for any explicit url rewrite rules to force https only?

Comment: Yes, it is classic cloud services. No rewrite for https...